# TensorFlow: getting invalid argument error, even though shape and dtype of feed dict is correct

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm having an issue with a ML model I'm building with TensorFlow. In the graph, I have a placeholder of type `tf.float32` and shape `[100,1]`:

```
dim_hidden = 100
...
h_prime_previous = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[dim_hidden, 1])
```

In the feed_dict, I pass in a NumPy array of type np.float32 and shape (100, 1):

```
h_prime_prev, logit_current = sess.run([h_prime, logit], feed_dict={y_previous: y_prev, h_prime_previous: h_prime_prev})
```

I know the size and type are correct because when I run this,

```
print("Shape: %s; Dtype: %s" % (h_prime_prev.shape, h_prime_prev.dtype))
```

it outputs the following:

```
Shape: (100, 1); Dtype: float32
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [100,1]
```

What could the issue be? I've run into it before, but I simply had to update TensorFlow and it worked. This time, however, I'm out of tricks, as TensorFlow is up to date. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I also got an insight from someone that it could be that I set h_prime_previous to something else somewhere in the code. That, however, is not happening, so that is definitely not the issue.

Comment: Can you print `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` and see how many placeholders you have? I suspect you have 3 placeholders and only feeding 2

Comment: Sorry, how can I find amount of placeholders after executing that line?

Also, just from doing a simple Ctrl+F, I can tell you that there are 6 placeholders, but I am calling sess.run() multiple times in a session, as I have have two variable-length segments in the graph which need to be unrolled separetely.

Comment: All six variables are feed in at some point throughout the session.

Comment: All dependent placeholders have to be fed during all run calls. You can "fix" the error by changing your run call to do `feed_dict={y_previous: y_prev, h_prime_previous: h_prime_prev, "Placeholder:0": np.zeros((100, 1)).as_type(np.float32)})`

Comment: Wow, that fixed it! Couple of questions: why/how did that work, and why do you say "fix"? I wager that both of those questions have the same answer. Feel free to answer those questions as an Answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There's a node called "Placeholder" in the graph that you are not feeding. Note that every time you call "placeholder" that creates a new placeholder node, so you may have some placeholders in the graph that you don't have any references to in your Python script